# Use php to populate javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, overlay, marker

All,
I have the following bit of code:

```
function addPoints() {

newpoints[0] = new Array(41.45998, 87.59643, icon0, 'Place', 'Content to open'); 

    for(var i = 0; i < newpoints.length; i++) {
       var point = new GPoint(newpoints[i][1],newpoints[i][0]);
       var popuphtml = newpoints[i][4] ;
       var marker = createMarker(point,newpoints[i][2],popuphtml);
       map.addOverlay(marker);
   }
}
```

There is other code around this to display the marker on my map. However this value is hardcoded. I have a PHP/mySQL database that has lat/long coordinates along with some other values. Say I have like three entries that I want to create markers for. How would I pass the addPoints function the lat/long that I got from my database so I can use it in this function correctly?

I updated my code to look like the following for the addPoints:

```
function addPoints(num, lat, long) {
newpoints[num] = new Array(lat, long, icon0, 'Place', 'Stuff name'); 
alert("The newpoints length is: "+newpoints.length);
for(var i = 1; i < newpoints.length; i++) {
    var point = new GPoint(newpoints[i][1],newpoints[i][0]);
    var popuphtml = newpoints[i][4] ;
    var marker = createMarker(point,newpoints[i][2],popuphtml);
    map.addOverlay(marker);
}
}
```

I call this function by doing this:

```
<script> 
    addPoints('<?php echo json_encode($num_coordinates); ?>','<?php echo json_encode($lat_coordinates); ?>', '<?php echo json_encode($long_coordinates); ?>');
</script>
```

It doesn't work though. When I try not to pass it to javascript and just output the lat coordinates for example. I get the following output:

```
{"1":"40.59479899","2":"41.4599860"}
```

Which are the correct coordinates in my array. No markers get created though. Any ideas on what to do next or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP executes on the server before getting sent to the the client.  Therefor, if you can do things like this:

`newpoints[0] = new Array(<?php echo $lattitude;?>, <?php echo $longitude;?>, icon0, 'Place', 'Content to open');`

Where `$lattitude` and `$longitude` are values that you pulled out of you database with PHP.

When this page is requested by the client, your php code executes, real values get plugged in where those php tags are making it look like the example you provided, and then it gets sent to the client.

If you want to change these values using JS on the client, or fetch new ones from the server, let me know and I'll add an example of that.

**EDIT:**

Okay, in light of your comments, it sounds like you've got a few options. Here's one:

When the user selects a category (restaurants, bars, etc) you pass that category as a url parameter and reload either the whole page, or just the map part of it (depends on your set up but might be worth investigating).  Your link would look something like this:

`http://www.your-domain-here.com/maps.php?category=bars`

Maps.php is ready to catch the category using the `$_GET` array:

`$category = $_GET['category'];  //'bars'`

Your php then grabs the appropriate location data from the database (I'll leave that part to you) and sticks it in a variable that your JS-controlled map will be able to use:

```
//JS in maps.php  -  you could add this var to the window object
// if you have separated js files...
var locationCoords = <?php echo json_encode($arrayOfCoordinatesFromDB);?>;
```

When you page loads on the client machine, it now has an array of coordinates to use for the map ready to go in the `locationCoords` variable.

Then, depending on which coordinates you need to display on the map, you pass them as arguments to your `addPoints()` using standard Javascript (nothing tricky here).

That's how I'd do it.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I have a loop to also display the things on my page. I'll send in various coordinates. Would I need to pass the variables to the addpoints function like addPoints(<?php echo $i; ?>, <?php echo $lattitude;?>, <?php echo $longitude;?>, icon0, 'Place', 'Content to open')?

Comment: I think I see where you're going with this, but let me ask before giving you the long answer:  1) It seems like you need to be able pass in new coordinates as the user interacts with the map.  Is that correct?  2) I imagine that you want to be able to get coordinates from the server when you need them, as opposed to loading all possible coordinates the first time your page downloads.  Is that correct?

Comment: So my scenarios is say I'm loading restaurants and there are 10 of them. I'm trying to pass in the lat/long of each one of them to create the markers. Then the user might select bars and then I'll have to pass in 15 coordinates etc. I'm trying to do it from within PHP script because I'm doing other stuff with zip codes etc.

Comment: can you please take a look at my edits that I made to my original post. I tried to do what you instructed but I'm missing something I believe. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would go add some debug traces to your `addPoints()` function to be sure that the right values are going where you'd like them to go.  If you're not familiar with `console` you should check it out.  It comes pre-packaged in Chrome, but I think if you're using Firefox you'll need to get the Firebug plugin.  Anyway, then you can see what the actual values are in the method using stuff like `console.log("My var: " + myVar)';` .  It looks like something is breaking on the JS side, so, it will be interesting to see what you find. Good luck!

Comment: Here's a link to a good intro on the the Chrome JS debugging tools:  http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html

Comment: When I output the variables I get the following: console.log("My num is: " + num);
console.log("My lat is: " + lat);
console.log("My lat length is: " + lat.length); I'm just not sure why my array length isn't working.
console.log("My long is: " + long);

When I get the output, I get the following:

My num is: {"1":1,"2":2}
My lat is: {"1":"40.59479899","2":"41.4599860"}
My lat length is: 36
My long is: {"1":"-75.5549650","2":"-87.596430"}

Comment: Ha ha, all I can tell you there is 'good luck!'  It looks like you've got a bug somewhere, and now you have the tools to track it down, so I'll leave you to it.  Your original question about using php to get your js set up has been answered though.  So, you should mark an answer correct on this question, and if you need to, start a new question for other issues if you get stuck.  It sounds to me like you have the things you need to figure it out though.  If it's anything like my bugs, it's probably something simple.  Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

An easy and clean way to pass an array from PHP to JavaScript is to simply `echo` the `json_encode` version of the array.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo 'var values = '.json_encode($array).';';
```

Comment: I tried to put this in my PHP: <script type="text/javascript">
          addPoints('0', <?php echo $lattitude;?>, <?php echo $longitude;?>, 'Content to open');         </script> Then I updated my addPoints to accept those arguments

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as echoing the php values.
`new Array(<?php echo $php_lat;?>, <?php echo $php_long;?>, icon0 etc...`

Answer (score 0):

I made a dynamic banner with this javascript array initialization. It works fine when the javascript is embedded in php.

```
    <?php
      // This is our php array with URLs obtained from the server
      $urlsPHP = ["img/img01.jpg","img/img02.jpg","img/img03.jpg"];

      return = "
        //...Some HTML...

        <script type='text/javascript'>

        // Now we use this inside the javascript
        var urlsJavaScript = ".stripslashes(json_encode($urlsPHP)).";

        //...Some javascript style to animate the banner...
        </script>
      ";


      // if we print this:
      echo stripslashes(json_encode($urlsPHP));
      // We obtain:
      // ["img/banner/bak01.jpg","img/banner/bak02.jpg","img/banner/bak03.jpg"]
      // This is a good syntax to initialize our javascript array


      // if we print this:
      echo json_encode($urlsPHP);
      // We obtain:
      // ["img\/banner\/bak01.jpg","img\/banner\/bak02.jpg","img\/banner\/bak03.jpg"]
      // This is not a good syntax to initialize our javascript URLs array
?>
```